# usage of driver_data member of I2C device id table

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

I am trying to understand I2C client drivers. As per my understanding before registering I2C driver we have to define `i2c_device_id` table and device tree compatible table.

I have following doubts. Could please help me to understand.

1) The definition of `i2c_device_id` structure contains two members (`name`, `driver_data`). The 1st member (`name`) is used to define the device name which will be used during driver binding, what is the use of the 2nd member (`driver_data`).

2) Driver binding will happen based on `i2c_device_id` table or device tree compatible string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

> 1) The definition of `i2c_device_id` structure contains two members (`name`, `driver_data`). The 1st member (`name`) is used to define the device name which will be used during driver binding, what is the use of the 2nd member (`driver_data`).

First you define the table (array) of `i2c_device_id` structures, like it's done in [max732x.c](/questions/tagged/max732x.c) driver:

```c
static const struct i2c_device_id max732x_id[] = {
    { "max7319", 0 },
    { "max7320", 1 },
    { "max7321", 2 },
    { },
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, max732x_id);
```

In your driver probe function you have one element of this array (for your particular device) as second parameter:

```c
static int max732x_probe(struct i2c_client *client,
                         const struct i2c_device_id *id)
```

Now you can use **`id->driver_data`** (which is unique to each device from the table) for your own purposes. E.g. for "max7320" chip `driver_data` will be `1`.

For example, if you have features which are specific to each device, you can create the array of features like this:

```c
static uint64_t max732x_features[] = {
    [0] = FEATURE0,
    [1] = FEATURE1 | FEATURE2,
    [2] = FEATURE2
};
```

and you can obtain features of your particular device from this array like this:

```c
max732x_features[id->driver_data]
```

Of course, you can use driver name for the same reason. But it would take more code and more CPU time. So basically if you don't need `driver_data` for your driver -- you just make it `0` for all devices (in device table).

> 2) Driver binding will happen based on `i2c_device_id` table or device tree compatible string.

To figure this out you can take a look at **`i2c_device_match()`** function (for example [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c?v=4.5#L503)). As you can see, first I2C core tries to match device by `compatible` string (OF style, which is Device Tree). And if it fails, it then tries to match device by id table.

Comment: Just to add to point #2, when the I2C core matches by compatible string, it also matches the model part of the `compatible = "manufacturer,model"` with the struct i2c_device_id array and passes that to i2c device probe. Neat!