# Example device-tree-aware i2c gpio driver for Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpio, i2c, device-tree

Is there a good example device-tree-aware i2c gpio driver for Linux?

I've been looking at gpio-pcf857x but it has a header file containing `struct pcf857x_platform_data` which is used in board files.

I am looking for a similar example, but where the i2c id is defined-in/retrieved-from the device tree.

Comment: Have you checked other drivers there? gpio-pca953x supports it at least. ID is retrived via compatible strings as far as I know.

Comment: Take a look at [max732x.c](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=max732x.c) driver. Corresponding bindings documentation (for driver references you are looking for) is at [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio?id=refs/tags/v4.11-rc7).

Comment: @SamProtsenko I used the max732.c as a base and it worked well.  Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @chrisdew Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [max732x.c](/questions/tagged/max732x.c) driver ([code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpio/gpio-max732x.c)). As for I2C ID table usage -- see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606448/usage-of-driver-data-member-of-i2c-device-id-table/27934228#27934228) answer.

Corresponding bindings documentation (for driver references you are looking for) is at [Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.